# Spectrogram date changed to 1970 when I use set_major_formatter and locator

Tags: python

I was trying to plot spectrogram by using 'plt.specgram'.

The date was from 2005-2007 but it moved to 1970.

```
    df=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
    df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
    df=df.set_index('Date')
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    plt.specgram(df, Fs=1)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formmater(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=3))
```

(Please don't care about the color but date)

[image]

In this case, what I have to do to use right date range?

e.g.

```
Date Value
2005-05-01 0.52264
2005-05-02 0.45656
... ...
2007-02-27 0.558954
2007-02-28 0.679884
```

Comment: Pls share some sample data so that this can be replicated

Comment: Yeap I applied. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) before setting the date index.

```
df=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df=df.reset_index()
df=df.set_index('Date')
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.specgram(df, Fs=1)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formmater(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=3))
```